# How to avoid printing a backslash with special characters in a string

Tags: python, string

I would like an output of `Siti's father says, "Hello."`.

However, the closest I've gotten to is:

```
s = "Siti's father says, \"Hello\""
```

with `s` being a variable to contain the required output.

The problem arises when I do `print("Siti's father says, \"Hello\"")` and get the perfect output, but when I assign the the above text to a variable `s`, I get a different output when defining `s`. I get: `'Siti\'s father says, "Hello"'`

What should I change to get the perfect output, assuming I can only use escape codes to get the desired output?

Comment: Sorry, what's the difference between "assign[ing] the above bolded text to a variable s" and "defining s"? Can you show the exact code you're using for both cases?

Comment: Are you printing the string, or the `repr` of the string?

Comment: The single quote shows up escaped because it's printed within single quotes. If it was not the first single quoted string would simply end at 'Siti'

Comment: What problem **exactly** are you trying to solve?

Comment: `s = 'Siti\'s father says, "Hello."'`

Comment: `s = '''Siti's father says, "Hello."'''` has no escape codes at all. It works by using Python's triple quote way to denote a string, which can include almost anything other than another triple quote.

Comment: @Kevin when i say "assigning the bolded text to a variable s", i mean that you put a value to the variable, for example s = "Hello World". when i say defining s, i mean typing 's' in the shell, and expecting the value of s being returned, assuming s was already defined before that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you display a variable or directly enter a string into the Python shell, it will be wrapped in single quotes.

```
>>> "String"    
'String'
```

Python escapes the single quote in your string when you display it because it's wrapped in single quotes. Otherwise, you would have something like this, and it would be unclear where the string ends:

```
'John's potato farm'
```

When you *print* it, it will appear with no quotes around it, as you would expect.

```
>>> s = "String"
>>> print(s)
String
```

To answer your question: create the string exactly as you're already doing it, and then print it out.

```
s = "Siti's father says, \"Hello.\""
print(s)
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a difference between a *string representation* and the string's *contents*. Whenever you `print` something, Python will output the string's content as is. Whenever you inspect a value (e.g. by just typing `s` on the prompt, or using `repr(s)`), Python will give you a *representation* of the value; it's trying to give you something that you can preferably use as is in Python source code. Example:

```
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 13, 15, 58, 37, 162588)
```

You can use `datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 13, 15, 58, 37, 162588)` literally like this in Python source code to recreate exactly this `datetime` object.

With strings it works the same. The *string literal* `"Siti's father says, \"Hello\""` creates a string with the *content* `Siti's father says, "Hello"`. A *representation* of that string would be any of these:

- `"Siti's father says, \"Hello\""`
- `'Siti\'s father says, "Hello"'`
- `'''Siti's father says, "Hello"'''`
- `'Siti\x27s father says, "Hello"'`
- *many further possibilities*

Python gives you *one* of these possible representations, namely the single-quote delimited one.